# Creating columns based on factor levels in base R reshape()

Tags: r, reshape

I am writing code to generate reports regarding study subjects and the timing of their follow-up visits. I have data that looks like this:

```
subj_id  timepoint           date
    100    3 month     2013-01-01
    101    3 month     2013-01-12
    102    3 month     2013-02-01
    ...        ...            ...
```

I would like to turn this into a "wide" data frame that I can then merge into another data frame that I have which shows when the subject should have been seen. Using `reshape`, I can do this, but I run into the following issue: if I reshape the data frame, I only get as many columns as it finds actual variables in the `timepoint` variable, even if there are possible values that have not yet been encountered in the database.

So, in my example, the variable `timepoint` is a factor with four levels: 3 month, 6 month, 9 month, and 12 month. However, at this point in the study, we haven't had anyone get past the 3 month visit, so the data is just lines 100, 101, and 102 above.

Using the following commands, you can get what I'm seeing (obviously this isn't how my data is created):

```
test_df <- data.frame(subj_id=c(100,101,102),
                      timepoint=c("3 month","3 month","3 month"),
                      date=c(as.Date("2013-01-01"),
                             as.Date("2013-01-12"),
                             as.Date("2013-02-01")))

test_df$timepoint <- factor(x=test_df$timepoint,
                            levels=c("3 month","6 month",
                                     "9 month","12 month"),
                            labels=c("3 month","6 month",
                                     "9 month","12 month"),
                            ordered=TRUE)

print(test_df)
>    subj_id timepoint       date
>  1     100   3 month 2013-01-01
>  2     101   3 month 2013-01-12
>  3     102   3 month 2013-02-01

levels(test_df$timepoint)
>  [1] "3 month"  "6 month"  "9 month"  "12 month"

reshape(data=test_df,v.names="date",
        timevar="timepoint",idvar="subj_id",direction="wide")

>    subj_id date.3 month
>  1     100   2013-01-01
>  2     101   2013-01-12
>  3     102   2013-02-01
```

What I would like to get would be something like this:

```
>    subj_id date.3 month  date.6 month  date.9 month  date.12 month
>  1     100   2013-01-01            NA            NA             NA
>  2     101   2013-01-12            NA            NA             NA
>  3     102   2013-02-01            NA            NA             NA
```

Is there a way to do this in base `reshape`? My current thought is to put four "fake" records in before I run `reshape` so that it will see four levels and create the data frame accordingly, but that seems kludgy at best. Is there a better way?

Comment: set `timepoint` to a factor setting the levels you need, then reshape

Comment: `timepoint` already is a factor though. It's just a factor where only one of the levels is in the data frame right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to programmatically extend the dataframe to add columns for the unpopulated levels.:

```
> new_df <- reshape(data=test_df,
+         timevar="timepoint",idvar="subj_id",direction="wide" )
> new_df
  subj_id date.3 month
1     100   2013-01-01
2     101   2013-01-12
3     102   2013-02-01
> new_df[ ,  setdiff(levels(test_df$timepoint) ,
                       factor(test_df$timepoint)) ] <- NA
> 
> new_df
  subj_id date.3 month 6 month 9 month 12 month
1     100   2013-01-01      NA      NA       NA
2     101   2013-01-12      NA      NA       NA
3     102   2013-02-01      NA      NA       NA
```

Note: Those column names will always need to be quoted because they have spaces. I never allow column names to stay that way.

Comment: Yeah, I'll definitely change the columns to not be quote-required. Thanks!